# Call to my struct dynamic member causes an infinite loop within my closure?

Tags: swift, infinite-loop

This made-up example displays a behavior I don't quite understand with structs/mutating functions/dynamic members. In a Playground, the changeStatus func will get called an infinite number of times and end up freezing Xcode. I expected a unique call to the closure to be made, executing the private method once.

```
// closure-returning subscript
@dynamicMemberLookup
struct LightManager {
    private var status = false
    private mutating func changeStatus() -> String {
        status = !status
        if status {
            return "on"
        } else {
            return "off"
        }
    }

    subscript(dynamicMember member: String) -> () -> Void {
        return {
    // following line causes an infinite loop
            let newStatus: String = self.changeStatus()
            print("Turn lights \(newStatus)")
        }
    }
}
let bedroomLights = LightManager()
bedroomLights.doStuff()
```

Comment: You can't call a mutating function from the non-mutating dynamic lookup function so your `self.changeStatus()` inside the subscript function doesn't call your mutating function, it calls the subscript again and passes in `"changeStatus"`

Comment: Ah, it figures... thanks!